# how to have a lazy loading on a chart,by scrolling horizontal more bars loaded

Tags: javascript

i have a chart which i have to show more than 300 columns or sometimes,i want to have a horizontal scroll on it and make it lazy-loading,by scrolling i can have a more data,is there such a option or chart?im working with kendo UI,but any chart example i would appreciate,just to get idea, for example show 20 columns(bar) on every  scroll:

Data:

```
var series = [ { department: "Home", sales: 200 }, 
           { department: "Sporting Goods", sales: 450 }, 
           { department: "Infant And Baby Clothing And Accessories", sales: 300 }, 
           { department: "Auto", sales: 125 }, { department: "Home", sales: 200 }, 
           { department: "Sporting Goods", sales: 450 }, 
           { department: "Infant And Baby Clothing And Accessories", sales: 300 }, 
           { department: "Auto", sales: 125 }, { department: "Home", sales: 200 }, 
           { department: "Sporting Goods", sales: 450 }, 
           { department: "Infant And Baby Clothing And Accessories", sales: 300 }, 
           { department: "Auto", sales: 125 }, { department: "Home", sales: 200 }, 
           { department: "Sporting Goods", sales: 450 }, 
           { department: "Infant And Baby Clothing And Accessories", sales: 300 }, 
           { department: "Auto", sales: 125 }, { department: "Home", sales: 200 }, 
           { department: "Sporting Goods", sales: 450 }, 
           { department: "Infant And Baby Clothing And Accessories", sales: 300 }, 
           { department: "Auto", sales: 125 }, { department: "Home", sales: 200 }, 
           { department: "Sporting Goods", sales: 450 }, 
           { department: "Infant And Baby Clothing And Accessories", sales: 300 }, 
           { department: "Auto", sales: 125 }, { department: "Home", sales: 200 }, 
           { department: "Sporting Goods", sales: 450 }, 
           { department: "Infant And Baby Clothing And Accessories", sales: 300 }, 
           { department: "Auto", sales: 125 }, { department: "Home", sales: 200 }, 
           { department: "Sporting Goods", sales: 450 }, 
           { department: "Infant And Baby Clothing And Accessories", sales: 300 }, 
           { department: "Auto", sales: 125 }, { department: "Home", sales: 200 }, 
           { department: "Sporting Goods", sales: 450 }, 
           { department: "Infant And Baby Clothing And Accessories", sales: 300 }, 
           { department: "Auto", sales: 125 }];
```

chart:

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
title: {
    text: "Kendo Chart Example"
},
dataSource: {
    data: series
},
series: [{
    type: "column",
    field: "sales",
    categoryField: "department"
}],
tooltip: {
    visible: true,

  }
 });
```

Live demo [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JZrAt/467/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the kendo-ui [custom pan and zoom](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/custom-pan-and-zoom) example:

> **Description**
>
> In addition to the built-in pan and zoom functionality, the Kendo UI chart supports custom panning and zooming as well.
>
> This example represents a custom implementation wiring the drag, dragEnd and zoom events of the chart. The idea is to intercept when these events are raised and fetch the data that has to be visualized in the chart, using a dynamical query by invoking the query method of the chart data source. Review the code snippets in the demo for more details.

**Added**

Perhaps you can implement a horizontal scrollbar that also pans.  Should be easier to position anywhere within the 'strip'

Consider the remote data source in the [Grid / Endless scrolling of remote data](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/endless-scrolling-remote) example. When hooked up to a grid with configuration option **`scrollable: { endless: true }`** the grid will 'autopage' as scrolling requires.  A study of the data callback returned from the server will show there is an item `__count: 77` which is used in the grid item page/count status footer.  The same kind of datasource and __count can be used to implement a manual scrollbar under the chart.

Consider this [dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/@RichardAD/oWEGEYIh) that uses a static data source but demonstrates the scrollbar.

The key features are adding a div for scrollbar and an inner div for content that is proportional to the number of data items in a pan view.

```
        var w = $("#scrollbar").width();
        $("#sb_content").width(chart.dataSource.data().length * w / viewSize);
```

and responding the scrollbar handle drag with the same kind of query that the pan handler does.

```
        $("#scrollbar").scroll(function(e) {
          var t = $(e.target);
          var pct = t.scrollLeft() / $("#sb_content").width();
          var skip = Math.round(pct * chart.dataSource.data().length);

          chart.dataSource.query({
            skip: skip,
            page: 0,
            pageSize: viewSize,
            sort: SORT
          });
        });
```

Another idea is to have a strip 'mini-map' showing the whole strip and active view

```
             active
             view
             +------+
+------------+------+---------------+ whole strip
|            .      .               |
|            .      .               |
+------------+------+---------------+
             +------+
```

Comment: thats great,the only thing is,when you reach the end of the chart by dragging,imagine 100 records,its not easy to get back to the first point,you have to drag many times to come back to the first bar